# Shrinking width of form

Tags: html, css, forms

I want my form to go in the top right hand corner. The form contains a label and input textbox. I have been trying to position the textbox and associated label using margin-left. I gradually started to realise though that the form was much bigger than met the eye.

This gives me a width of 1328px -

```
<form  ;method='GET'>
 
Test to see form size

</form>
```

I tried this

```
<form  style="width: 300px" method='GET'>
 
Test to see form size

</form>
```

[image]
But you can tell the overall form width is still 1328px.

How can I reduce the width of the form so it is the same size as the label and input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the form element and add an absolute position to it.

```
form{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Just to see if it moves to the top right corner.

Comment: Your solution was super simple to implement. And other than adjusting the numbers slightly for cosmetic reasons, I didn't have to change it all.